# What is the motive of $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, motives

$\DeclareMathOperator\Bun{Bun}$Let $X$ be a scheme over algebraically closed field $k$, $G$ a reductive group and $\Bun_G(X)$ the stack of $G$ bundles on $X$. Write $[\Bun_G(X)]\in K_\text{st}$ for its class in the Grothendieck ring of stacks (see [Ekdahl - The Grothendieck group of algebraic stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3143)).

What is $[\Bun_G(X)]$ for $X$ a curve? I've been told that this is a known result, but I might be wrong.

Secondly, is $[\Bun_G(X)]$ known when $X$ is a surface? If not in general then how about in “easy” cases, like $X=\mathbf{P}^2$ and $G=\operatorname{GL}_n$?

For the purposes of this question, “known” means expressible in terms of simpler classes like $[X^{(n)}]$.

---

*Edit:* It is true for curves (and I've heard for surfaces too but don't have a reference) that the cohomology of $\text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(X)$ is freely generated by the chern classes of the universal bundle $\mathscr{U}$ on $X\times \text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(X)$ (i.e. the components of $c_i(\mathscr{U})$ in $H^*(\text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(X))$). In these cases, the Poincare polynomial is
$$P(\text{Bun}_{\text{GL}_n}(X),t)\ =\ \prod_{i=0}^n \prod_{k=0}^{2i} (1+(-1)^{k+1}t^{2i-k})^{(-1)^{k+1}\dim H^k(X)}$$
which probably gives partial information as to what the motive should be (for instance, replace $t^2$ by $\mathbf{L}$ in the denominator).

Comment: TeX-style quotes `` '' don't work in MathJax, unfortunately.  I have edited to Unicode “”.

Comment: The paper "On the motivic class of the stack of bundles" by Behrend and Dhillon may be a start.

Comment: @WillSawin's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359114/what-is-the-motive-of-operatornamebun-xg#comment903738_359114): [Behrend and Dhillon - On the motivic class of the stack of bundles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870806003756) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2329314)).

Comment: Also this might be pedantic, but you need to complete the Grothendieck ring in some way before you make this computation, as $Bun_X(G)$ has infinitely many strata. (This is done in the reference above)

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks, I think that paper shows the answer was conjectured but not known in 2005. Hopefully it is known now and there is at least a conjecture for the surface case.

Comment: if someone had, it's very likely that they would cite that paper. I looked in the list of papers citing that one and didn't find it, but it's possible it's there. I actually don't think there is a conjecture even for $\mathbb P^2$. The structure of these spaces is just too wild - why would you expect a nice answer?